# React js server side rendering and host in IIS

Tags: reactjs, iis

How to host server side rendering application which developed in react js. Now I want to deployed in IIS. So, how can I achieve this.

anyone suggest any example.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to have node.js on your server. IIS will just proxy your app.

There is different ways how to achieve that:

1. With [IISNode project](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode):

Instructions you can find here:
http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/09/creating-10-minute-todo-listing-app-on.html

2. With ARR(Application Request Routing) module for IIS:

Instructions you can find here: https://adamtuttle.codes/blog/2015/add-node-to-existing-iis-server/

Comment: Great answer. Option 2 allows us to run a react dev server with all the benefits like live reloading, but under a custom domain eg not localhost.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install [IIS node](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode):

   - x64 - [https://github.com/azure/iisnode/releases/download/v0.2.21/iisnode-full-v0.2.21-x64.msi)
2. Install [URL rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).
3. Create Web.config with following declarations in `<configuration>/<system.webServer>`:

   ```
   <handlers>
       <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
   </handlers>

   <rewrite>
       <rules>

       <rule name="Server-side rendering" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url=".*" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
       </rule>
   </rules>
   ```

You can optionally exclude node_modules so they are not served by IIS:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
            <add segment="node_modules" />
        </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

4. Create node.js server, for example with [express.js](https://expressjs.com/):

   import express from 'express'

   const app = express()

   app.get('*', (req, res) => {
       /*render app here*/
   });

   app.listen(process.env.PORT);

Remember to bind to `process.env.PORT` as it is passed to your server by the IIS!

5. Render your app server side, for example like this:

   `const App = ({message}) => <div>Hello {message}</div>`

   `const template = ...`

(StackOverflow eats my tags embedded in js... so copy that and use string interpolation)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    </head>
      
    <body>
        <div id="app">${body}</div>
    </body>

    <script async src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'

const renderedComponent = renderToString(<App message={`from ${req.url}`} /> )
const html = template(renderedComponent)
res.send(html)
```

6. Configure your build tool and router.

You can create two separate build targets for the Webpack - one for the client and one for the server. You should also handle in-app routing but that depends on what library you are using.